# How to set subsample in lightgbm in R?

Tags: r, xgboost

There is a `subsample` parameter for the XGBoost (`xgb.train()` function in R). What is the corresponding subsample parameter for lightgbm in R?

In Python, the [parameter](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Parameters.md#io-parameters) is `bagging_fraction`.

Comment: I think `bagging_fraction` is working for R.

Comment: I tried it and I set bagging_fraction = 0.01 and there is no speed difference so I assume that it actually is not working.